# Refused to talk to me: 521 connection rejected

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have a Zimbra mail server running on a dynamic public IP. The incoming and outgoing mails are relayed through a AWS ec2 instance(running postfix) that has a static public IP. The AWS instance has proper reverse DNS entries, MX records and SPF setup.

This setup has been working fairly well for the last few years, but lately I am seeing an increased number of "Refused to talk to me: 521 connection rejected" errors.

When this happens none of the domains accepts mails from my relay server. Even telnet aspmx.l.google.com 25 gets rejected right away. Incoming mails are fine though. I can confirm that the IP or domain is NOT on any of the blacklists.

I fail to understand what could be the issue here. Does it make any difference if the Zimbra server's public IP is on a blacklist? I can confirm it never used to, not sure if things are different now?

Comment: It's the EC2 instance that has been blacklisted, not your Zimbra server. Right? Or where exactly is the rejection taking place?

Comment: No, EC2 IP or our domain is not on any blacklists.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Zimbra mailserver is on something like a DSL line, hence has a dynamic ip. Theres a good chance the ISP who provides this blocks outbound email ports - mine does on residential DSL lines, as a way to combat spambots running off of a botnet.

The next time this happens, try to telnet to any other server on port 25 which you had tested earlier. If you have an external VPS that does not have a mailserver installed, just run
sudo netcat -lkv 25
on that VPS to make it temporarily listen on port 25.